# Bypass windows authentication on a controller MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I've enabled Windows authentication on my mvc web application but I need it to be bypassed on the first page(so anyone can access HomeController\Index).How can this be achieved?

Here's my authentication logic:

```
<location path="~/DashboardController" />
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="Domain\MyUserName"/>
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

I've tried decorating the default dashboard controller Action with `[Authorize]` and `[Authorize(Users="*")]` but when I try access the home page the browser displays a prompt to enter credentials

Comment: I have the same problem. [AllowAnonymous] doesn't work when Windows Authentication is enabled. Browser always prompts to enter credentials for authentication.

Comment: @revobtz Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Add the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute to your Index method

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

    return View();
}
```

Or if you don't want to use attributes for what ever reason you can allow this via the web.config. (I'd avoid the web.config where possible and use attributes. [See this blog from Jon Galloway for more info](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-authentication-global-authentication-and-allow-anonymous))

```
<location path="HomeController/Index">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: I've tried that now, still getting the authentication dialog in Chrome when I run the web application

Comment: Are you running the site in IIS in both Windows Authentication and Anonymous authentication modes?

Comment: I'm still doing dev, trying to run it from VS 2013 using IISExpress.It's not even hitting the Action method if i put a break point on it.It's like the authentication kicks in before it picks up the [AllowAnonymous]

Comment: So if you click your Web Application in VS2013 and view the Property Window ( `CTL + W`, `P`) You should see options for `Anonymous Authentication` & `Windows Authentication` - these should both be enabled.

Comment: It says WIndowsAUthentication=Enbaled and AnonymousAuthentication=Disabled.I tried enabling AnonymousAUthentication and tried to run the site but still having the same isssue

Comment: Are you navigating directly to the Index method? Otherwise you will be prompted for credentials as the other pages require Windows Auth. Try setting your Start Page in your Project Properties to a specific page. e.g. `Views/Home/Index.cshtml`

Comment: I have the start up page configured in the RouteConfig.cs file - defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index",